# How to pair an Android Wear virtual device with an Android virtual device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I've got an Android AVD (nexus 5), which I'm trying to pair with an Android wear AVD. However, to pair the 'watch' with the 'phone', the phone needs the Android Wear app. This isn't installed, and the play store isn't there to install it. How can I install the Wear app on the 'phone'?